# How to prevent a Bluetooth headset to autoconnect without disabling Bluetooth?

Tags: 14.10, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

I have Xubuntu 14.10, with the package `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` installed, which works fine with my Bluetooth headset.

I find annoying though, that the headset is automatically connected to the computer, as very often I want it to be connected to another device.

Is there a way to disable the automatic connection? I can't simply disable Bluetooth as I have a Bluetooth mouse.

Comment: You can temporary disable bluetooth on you computer.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that doesn't work, because I have a BT mouse :-)

Comment: And why not include that in the question? ;)

Comment: The question becomes then which is initiating the connection - the computer, or the headset.  In the case of me, it's the bluetooth earbuds I have, but I don't think there's a way to disable it as the earbuds (read as a headset by Ubuntu) triggers the connection.

Comment: @Marcus: I edited the Elder Geek answer, please try the software solution. If you can get sucess with this method, please accept the answer. I have the user interface in Spanish and I badly translated the options, if I'm wrong in anything, please notify.

Comment: keep your bluetooth headphone either switched off or connected to other device ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Hardware solution:

1. Obtain a cheap USB mouse.
2. Put your Bluetooth mouse away somewhere safe.
3. Attach the USB Mouse
4. Open a terminal and issue the command `rfkill list` this will give you a listing of rf devices, preceded by an index number.
5. Issue the command  `rfkill block n` where `n` is the index number of the device you wish to block (in this case your bluetooth interface)

You can **re-enable the device** with the command `rfkill unblock n` where `n` is the index number of the device you wish to unblock (in this case your bluetooth interface)

**Note:** I don't have bluetooth so I tested this process with a different rf device.

---

#### Software solution:

1. Install blueman bluetooth manager from the Software Center or with this command:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install blueman
   ```

   Note: Installation requires the "universe" repository to be active in your software sources[.](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/utopic/universe/base/blueman)
2. Open Blueman from the dash.
3. Select the headset from the list
4. Click **Setup...**
5. A window will open up, on that window, check **Do not connect**.
6. Click **Next** button
7. You're done

You should be able to connect and disconnect bluetooth devices at will.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable solution; if nothing comes up in the next days, considering what  "Thomas W.", most likely, there is no other way (so that this answer would be acceptable.

Comment: Ok, if nobody posts a full software answer, I'll give the bounty to Elder.

Comment: @Helio edited answer to include possible software solution.

Comment: @ElderGeek: I edited your answer to improve S/W solution details.

Comment: @Helio Thank you for the edit. I can't believe I didn't check the software center.  Were you able to test? It looks like this will indeed do the trick based on the screenshot I found...

Comment: @ElderGeek: I tried it and seems to work. Now will see what says Marcus...

Comment: hell yeah! that works.

Comment: to be more specific, it worked somewhat unstably, but I'll leave that to the "tweaking" part :-)

Comment: If you run into bugs, please subscribe to existing bugs that affect you or in the case of new bugs, report them at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blueman/ to help the developers squash them! ;-)

Comment: @Marcus, please edit the answer to enhance it with a good screenshot and your method based on experience (not trust instead of disable...) and I'll give the bounty to the question.

Comment: @ElderGeek: I think that you would remove the hardware answer, as Marcus accepted the answer because the software answer was there... and works.

Comment: @Helio I believe that both answers are valid. Someone with the same problem and a USB mouse on the shelf might prefer the hardware answer.. The hardware answer may also be more "future proof" than the software one depending on the state of ongoing development.

Comment: "Setup" is missing in blueman 2.2.4

Comment: Setup is still missing (2.3.5)

Answer (score 7):

To prevent a specific device from automatically connecting while leaving it paired, you can `untrust` the device in `bluetoothctl`.

```
$ bluetoothctl
# devices
Device <MAC> <ID>
# untrust <MAC>
```

If you turn the device  off and on now (while watching the output of`bluetoothctl`) you can see it start to connect, but then ask you to trust it and (with no input) eventually timeout. The device will stop sending these connection requests once it pairs with something else.

```
[CHG] Device <MAC> Connected: no
[CHG] Device <MAC> Connected: yes
Authorize service
[agent] Authorize service <UUID> (yes/no): Request canceled
[CHG] Device <MAC> Connected: no
```

If you want to connect the device, you can accept the trust request from `bluetoothctl` (or maybe your GUI depending on your windows manager). You can re-enable autoconnect with `trust <MAC>` in `bluetoothctl`.

Comment: A combination of untrust _and an explicit disconnect_ prevents auto-reconnect for me. That said, it's still annoying that you must disconnect each time. I can pair multiple devices with my headset. Usually, if I connect to another device, the previous one will be disconnected. But, Ubuntu always tries to steal back the connection unless I walk back to the computer and click on disconnect.

Answer (score 5):

Another valid, simple solution: don't trust the device. When the connection popup shows up, just (click on) `Deny`.

Answer (score 3):

Answers so far were helpful, but didn't solve the problem for me: I'm using google Pixel Buds Series-A, and whenever I power on my laptop, it steals the buds audio connection from my phone.

- Marking the device as `untrusted` didn't help.
- `unpair`ing is not convenient - to pair I would need to take the buds out of my ears and put them back in the charging case.
- Blueman is supposed to have an option to `block` a device, but I don't see it Blueman 2.2.4. https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/pull/1648

**How I got it to work** with `bluetoothctl`:

1. Find the device address in the output of `bluetoothctl devices`

   ```
   $ bluetoothctl devices
   Device 0C:C4:13:12:34:56 Buds
   Device CD:92:84:12:34:56 MX Master 2S
   ```
2. Block the mac address `bluetoothctl block 0C:C4:13:12:34:56`

   ```
   $ bluetoothctl block 0C:C4:13:12:34:56
   Changing 0C:C4:13:12:34:56 block succeeded
   ```
3. Now, when I want to connect to the buds again, I need to unblock them first:

   ```
   bluetoothctl unblock 0C:C4:13:12:34:56 && bluetoothctl connect 0C:C4:13:12:34:56
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The key thing that worked for me after having tried everything was to go to /etc/bluetooth and edit the main.conf file.

Set ReconnectAttempts=0

By default its commented out. After doing this my bluetooth devices finally stopped autoconnecting.

I'm not sure if the main.conf file is for blueman specifically so maybe install that too.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, man! It really helps. Thank you so much. I was so angry when my Linux take away on themselves from smartphone my BT headphones again and again.

Comment: This does not seem to work on Kubuntu 23.10. My headphones still autoconnect as soon as I turn them on.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `blueman` package and run `blueman-manager`. Right-click on your headset and choose Remove.

This should "unpair" your headset. You can always re-pair using the same tool if you want to connect again.

It's not perfect, but may be a usable workaround for you.

Comment: I think that rather than unpairing, it's somewhat more efficient not to trust the device, and click on "deny" when they connection pop-up shows.

Comment: I am trying the option to "Setup" --> "Don't connect" mentioned in the other answer. It seems to be working

Comment: @Marcus Thanks, I really think this is the best answer, because I had tried other suggestions on the internet but only your suggestion worked on my system. Moreover people can have a hard time finding your suggestion because it's somewhat "hidden" inside a comment. Can you please convert it to answer and I'm sure you'll get many upvotes :)

Comment: @SebMa Wrote the answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

My problem:

I connected laptop with airpods. After this action, laptop continue to steal connection, if i deside reconnect airpods to phone. All answers in this tread didnt help.

Lets look at the content of `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`:

```
# ReconnectAttempts define the number of attempts to reconnect after a link lost. Setting the value to 0 disables reconnecting feature.
# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found. This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged in later on. Defaults to 'true'.
```

Based on description, u can just run these commands in your shell and your device will stop steal connection from other devices:

```
echo "ReconnectAttempts=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
echo "AutoEnable=false" | sudo tee -a /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```