# How can I disable bluetooth auto connect for specific devices?

Tags: bluetooth

I have bluetooth headsets and speakers that I connect to different computers. These bluetooth devices will connect to the last computer they were connected to when powered on, but I'd like to disable that for these specific devices that we use among different computers. As it stands, it is quite annoying to have to find the computer the device auto connected to and manually disconnect before being able to connect to the new computer. Is it possible to disable auto connect for specific devices? And if so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can `untrust` a device in `bluetoothctl` to leave it paired but prevent autoconnection.

See my full answer on a similar question with more votes (sorry :sweaty smile:):

https://askubuntu.com/a/1336382/27198

Comment: What if I only want to turn off the automatic connection, but I still want to manually connect sometimes? My laptop is constantly grabbing my bluetooth headphones even if I am listening to something on them from my phone. Super annoying! But I still want to be able to connect my computer sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

User Elder Geek provided a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605878/how-to-prevent-a-bluetooth-headset-to-autoconnect-without-disabling-bluetooth)  that looks like it may work:

> 1. Install blueman bluetooth manager from the Software Center or with this command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install blueman
>    ```
>
>    Note: Installation requires the *universe* repository to be enabled in your software sources.
> 2. Open Blueman from the Dash.
> 3. Select the headset from the list
> 4. Click *Setup...*
> 5. A window will open up, on that window, check Do not connect.
> 6. Click the *Next* button.

Comment: I tried this with no success.

Answer (score -3):

In console type one by one:

```
bluetoothctl
devices
```

to get the address of the device you want.

Create a text file anywhere on your computer with any name.
(Try to stay away from root or certain system folders, you can use home or desktop)

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5; echo "disconnect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" | bluetoothctl
```

Type that in the text file and save.
(XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is device address)
In properties of the file, or in console, make the file executable.
In system settings, add the file to autostart.
(Or in console, use whatever you are using to autostart programs or scripts.)

In the code above;

```
#!/bin/bash
```

turns the file into an executable script.

```
sleep 5
```

makes it wait for 5 seconds.

```
echo
```

Writes the command next to it.

```
disconnect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

disconnects from the device, whose address is specified as XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

```
bluetoothctl
```

is the bluetooth environment command to configure bluetooth devices.

If 5 seconds is not enough, use a bigger number.
If you change the `disconnect` command to `connect`, you can use the same script to auto connect bluetooth devices.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this solves the problem. The issue is that the disconnect command needs to run if the headphones are powered on and they get autoconnected to the wrong computer. The desired result is to disable autoconnect for a specific device. This solution could work if you wanted the headphones to disconnect on startup of the computer, but that's not what I'm after.